# Is leaving completely empty columns in Bootstrap a bad design/programming practice?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's what I mean.

I have a log in button on the top right of the page, and the title of the page centered in the middle.

However, the only way I found to center the tile on the div, was the center the div itself on the page, which was col-md-9.

I tried using CSS to center the Div, but I couldn't make it work, so the workaround I found was the center the div by using another column before the column where the Title is positioned.

However, this new div is completely empty. I might put a logo in it later on, but I planned for the top right of the page to be empty.

Is there something bad with having empty divs?

Is there a better way to implement this?

Code for reference.

```
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 id="TEXT">OH SNIP</h1>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button id="dpBt" class="dropbtn"></button>
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <form id="logIn" action="api/users" method="POST">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='username' class='sr-onl'>Username</label>
                                <input id='username' type='username' required='' placeholder='Username' class='form-control' name='username'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='password' class='sr-onl'>Password</label>
                                <input id='password' type='password' required='' placeholder='Password' class='form-control' name='password'>
                            </div>
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <button id="btnLogin" class='btn btn-block'>Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <hr>
                        <input id="btnRegisto" type="button" class="btn btn-block" value="Sign up">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You could use a [column offset (docs)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting) to centre the column if the empty column bothers you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leave blank columns, but a better approach provided by Bootstrap is to use offsets.

Here is an example from Bootstrap 3.3

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
```

Here's an example that better fits what your trying to do.  Notice the offset for the button.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/login/">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="id_username" name="username" value="" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```